# get aspxcombobox value using javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, devexpress

I have a aspxcombobox with ID="comboSubjectCategory", can I get the selected value/text using javascript function? thanks lot...I tried this but it does not works.

```
function getValue() {
   var combo = document.getElementById('comboSubjectCategory').value;
   alert(combo);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ASPxComboBox is not a simple HTML element. In the browser, it is represented by the [ASPxClientComboBox Class](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/clsDevExpressWebASPxEditorsScriptsASPxClientComboBoxtopic). Use its [GetValue](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxEditorsScriptsASPxClientEditBase_GetValuetopic), [GetText](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxEditorsScriptsASPxClientComboBox_GetTexttopic) or [GetSelectedItem](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxEditorsScriptsASPxClientComboBox_GetSelectedItemtopic) methods to obtain the selected value.

You can obtain the ASPxClientComboBox instance by the name assigned to the [ClientInstanceName](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxEditorsASPxEditBase_ClientInstanceNametopic) property of the ASPxComboBox control.

**See Also:** [Client-Side Functionality](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument6908)

Comment: thanks, its works, i used "GetText" in javascript function and I also add clientInstantName for my combobox. For example: "comboSubjectCategory" is my clientInstantName and therefore in my javascript function: comboSubjectCategory.GetText;

Answer (score -1):

```
var combo = document.getElementById('<%= comboSubjectCategory.ClientID %>');
var val = combo.options[combo.selectedIndex].value;
```